# how get the count if the customer has activated certs three times in same year with SP

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have got DB table schema `ActInfo` like this

```
customerName     customerEmail   CertificateID     Activated_On
 A                A@xxx.com         xxxx           2013-05-20 04:02:39.000
  A              A@xxxx.com         xxxxx          2013-09-11 03:09:34.000
 A              A@xxxx.com          xxxxx          2013-04-03 06:09:34.000
```

We can see from above data that A has activated certificate three times in a year but i need to give a warning that he has activated three times per year

Is it possible with storedprocedure to check the count if user has activated the certificate more than twice in same year...Certificate ID are same or not it does not matter.

Would any one please help on this query

Many thanks for advance...

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?  You have listed 2008 and 2012.  What have you already tried?  Do you want the warning for the last calendar year, or the last 365 days rolling?

Comment: @pratapk...dnt u think simple group by will work ... but i am not sure that u meant tht ... Select customerName from cust where year(Activated_On) = 2015 group by customerName having count(customerName) > 2

Comment: @Dhaval thanks.. but 2015 is hardcoded  one we are not meant to be hardcoded right

Comment: @pratapk yes it is obivious 2015 must not be hardcoded ... i was just giving idea(that is why it is a comment)  .... but loosley ur query would look like that only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this approach, I start with the most recent activation per customer, then outer join to all the activations for that customer within the past year.  We ultimately return the customer and the count of activations within the past year.

```
SELECT
    DerivedLastActivationByCustomer.CustomerName AS [Customer Name],
    COUNT(ActInfo.CustomerName) AS [Activations in Past Year]
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        CustomerName,
        MAX(Activated_On) AS [Last Activation]
    FROM
        ActInfo
    GROUP BY
        CustomerName
    ) DerivedLastActivationByCustomer
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ActInfo ON DerivedLastActivationByCustomer.CustomerName = ActInfo.CustomerName AND DATEDIFF(d, ActInfo.ActivatedOn, DerivedLastActivationByCustomer.[Last Activation]) < 365
GROUP BY
    DerivedLastActivationByCustomer.CustomerName
```

Now, if you want to turn this into a stored procedure, you have options.  You don't specify how this SP should work.  In the simplest possible form, you could use just the above query and return the recordset.

Or, you could take the customer as an input parameter (i.e. `@Cust`), then use it as part of the `WHERE` clause of the inner query to only return info on that one specific customer.

Another possible approach would be to put a `WHERE` clause on the outermost `SELECT` statement to only return those with three or more activations (i.e. `WHERE [Activations in Past Year] >= 3`

Based on comments, the SP would be:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetActivationsInPriorYear] 
(
@Cust nvarchar(max), 
@ActivationCount int OUTPUT
)

AS

SELECT
    DerivedLastActivationByCustomer.CustomerName AS [Customer Name],
    @ActivationCount = COUNT(ActInfo.CustomerName) --AS [Activations in Past Year]
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        CustomerName,
        MAX(Activated_On) AS [Last Activation]
    FROM
        ActInfo
    WHERE
        ActInfo.CustomerName = @Cust
    GROUP BY
        CustomerName
    ) DerivedLastActivationByCustomer
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ActInfo ON DerivedLastActivationByCustomer.CustomerName = ActInfo.CustomerName AND DATEDIFF(d, ActInfo.ActivatedOn, DerivedLastActivationByCustomer.[Last Activation]) < 365
GROUP BY
    DerivedLastActivationByCustomer.CustomerName

GO
```

Comment: Many thanks for the reply.. i want only per specific customer that means i need to pass customer name to that SP  and i would like to get if the user has activated more than two in that year ..

Comment: I want to restrict the user not activate more than two certificates in same year .. if the user has activated two certs in 2015 and he if he wants more in 2015 we will  be giving warning to him not to activate more in 2015 ..this is right

Comment: I am getting this error when i run your query. ".Column 'DerivedLastActivationByCustomer.customer_name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: hi many thanks .. i just need customer as input entry and is it possible to get the count if he activated more than two in same year(for example in 2015)..

Comment: SP def provided.  Note that this is more flexible than being constrained to one calendar year - this is counting activations within the past year of the most recent activation, not just within the same calendar year.  The calendar year variation would be much simpler.

Comment: hmm i need to restrict to one calendar year need to get the count in that year only ...